# Laravel 5.0 query database using a form

Tags: database, laravel

I am new to Laravel 5.0 and I'm having trouble using a form to query a database and return the results to a view. Form accepts user input for week number and this week number should be used to query the database table. Any help would be appreciated.

Form inside my view

```
<form action="" method="get">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="weekNum" placeholder="Typein Week Number"> 
       <span class="input-group-btn"> 
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
           </button>
       </span>
   </div>
</form>
```

Route::get('/search', 'shopsalescontroller@index');

Controller

```
class shopsalescontroller extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $weekNum = Request::input('WeekNumber');
        $result = shopsales::where('WeekNumber','=',$weekNum)->get();
        return $result; 
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not calling the correct url i guess, your controller says /search but you are only using action=""

Answer (score 0):

try to change your form action to this `action="{{ url('/search') }}"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your route in your view. Add the following

```
<form action="{{ url('/search') }}" method="get">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="weekNum" placeholder="Typein Week Number"> 
       <span class="input-group-btn"> 
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
           </button>
       </span>
   </div>
</form>
```

You could also use the route helper if you added a name to your route

Comment: Ok so i managed to be able to return the data to a view. Now i have 3 seperate database queries that I need to run. I have been able to run one and return it to a view. I copied the code exactly and changed a few names, setup my routes and controller and now getting undefined variable  error. HELP!!

Comment: Hi thanks for asking another question. You'll need to open a new one question for it to be answered. Don't forget to mark this one as complete